# Xubuntu - airplane mode after suspend PC

Tags: xubuntu

I have a problem please with Xubuntu 19.10 with MSI GS75:

After putting my pc to suspend, it goes into airplane mode. My Wi-Fi and Bluetooth are disabled.
And I can't get out of airplane mode with the function key + F10.
I am stuck on this airplane mode.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Try enabling secure boot in bios > will disable inbuilt WiFi modules on Linux

Comment: My secure boot is disabled. I tried to enabled it, it doesn't change my problem

Answer (score 0):

From [Wifi_is_hardblocked_(airplane_mode)_after_waking_up_from_suspend](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MSI_GS65#Wifi_is_hardblocked_(airplane_mode)_after_waking_up_from_suspend)

```
A way to mitigate this is by setting systemd to hibernate instead of suspending.

Edit - /etc/systemd/logind.conf

HandleSuspendKey=hibernate  

HandleLidSwitch=hibernate
```

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem. if I close my cover, it shuts down my PC, and I lose my open tabs ... and if I click on the sleep button, the PC goes to sleep, but airplane mode is activated